# GetOrder not returning buyer info on Amazon Orders API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm not sure if I am missing something here, so let me take you through my logic flow:

1. Call GetOrderList, returning orders within the a given timeframe, and with a status of Unshipped, represented by the enum "OrderStatusEnum.Unshipped".
2. Call GetOrders, passing a list of the orderIDs from the previous operation above.

According to the documentation:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/Orders_Datatypes.html

I should be getting back buyer info - more specifically the amazon generated email address for the customer. However the Order datatype (which is shared between both calls), doesn't have the properties for this data. See Below:

[image: Order DataType]

Am I missing something, or is this an issue with the C# Client Library?

Here is the method I wrote to call GetOrders:

```
public List<Order> GetOrders( List<Order> orderList )
    {
        var orders = new List<Order>();

        if ( orderList.Count <= 50 )
        {
            var request = new GetOrderRequest
            {
                SellerId = this.Context.MerchantID,
                AmazonOrderId = new OrderIdList { Id = orderList.Select( ol => ol.AmazonOrderId ).ToList() }
            };

            var response = GetService().GetOrder( request );
            orders.AddRange( response.GetOrderResult.Orders.Order );
        }
        else
        {
            var orderIds = orderList.Select( ol => ol.AmazonOrderId ).ToList();
            var pages = orderIds.Count/50;

            if ( orderIds.Count%50 > 0 )
                pages++;

            for ( var i = 0; i < pages; i++ )
            {
                var request = new GetOrderRequest
                {
                    SellerId = this.Context.MerchantID,
                    AmazonOrderId = new OrderIdList { Id = orderIds.Skip( i * 50 ).Take( 50 ).ToList() }
                };

                var response = GetService().GetOrder( request );
                orders.AddRange( response.GetOrderResult.Orders.Order );
            }

        }

        return orders;

    }
```

Which has a call to GetService():

```
public MarketplaceWebServiceOrders.MarketplaceWebServiceOrders GetService()
    {
        var config = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersConfig
        {
            ServiceURL = this.ServiceUrl + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment.OrdersEndpoint"]
        };

        var service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient(
            this.ApplicationName, 
            this.ApplicationVersion, 
            this.Context.AccessKeyID, 
            this.Context.SecretAccessKey, 
            config
        );

        return service;
    }
```

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a potential issue with the client library as the data I'm looking for is present when making a request via the scratchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by building from the provided source files. It looks like the supplied dlls are not not the correct version, or are built from a different source.

After bulding my own dlls and making my code work with it, I am getting the data I expect.

Comment: Hi, is there any api available to get order informations such as tracking number,carrier info etc.